# Extracting 1d arrays from 3d numpy array using 2d boolean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, reshape

Say I have a 3d numpy array:

```
i, j, k = 10, 3, 4

arr = np.arange(120).reshape(i, j, k)
```

and a 2d boolean array:

```
mask = np.random.random((j, k)) > 0.5

n = mask.sum()
```

I want to be able to extract the 1d arrays from `arr` along its 1st dimension which correspond with the `True` values of `mask`. The result should have shape, `(i, n)`. How could this be done?

I pulling up some old code and for some reason I was doing `arr[mask]` but this gives a shape of `(n, k)` (I'm not sure why) and a warning:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 10949 but corresponding boolean dimension is 11
```

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: Yes it did thanks! This makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply mask along the last two axes -

```
arr[:,mask]
```